# Retrieving item values from a workflow task dialog box to put in a web part in the same box

Tags: workflow, visual-web-part

I have implemented a workflow and now I would like to develop a web part to be used with the Edit and View forms that are loaded in the modal dialog during, say, an approval task.

May I know how do I retrieve the values of the Item that the current task is working on so that I could do with the values in my web part?